# FFMpeg - Trim and concatenate in one step

Tags: ffmpeg, trim

In [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1150276/) [gyan](/questions/tagged/gyan) responded that it is possible to trim and concatenate in one step. This seems like a straight-forward and common function but I've not been able to find how to do that in my searches.  Specifically, if I have two MPEG transport stream files, say `VidA.ts` and `VidB.ts`, what ffmpeg command would (for example) take the last 180 seconds of `VidA` and combine (concat) it with the first 10 minutes of `VidB` into `VidC.ts`?

(Since I don't think you can trim *the last 180 seconds* without knowing the duration, assume the duration of all input files is 15 minutes; they may not be, but I can do simple math okay. lol)

Further, I would like to know if it is even possible (with one command) to output three files, as in the example given, where

- `VidC01.ts` is the first 12 minutes of `VidA`,
- `VidC02.ts` is the "trimmed and concatenated" file, and
- `VidC03.ts` is the last 5 minutes of `VidB`.

I know how to do all this in numerous steps, I'm just feeling naive thinking there is a way, I just haven't been able to discover it yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic template would be

```
ffmpeg
-t 12:00 -i VidA.ts
-ss 12:00 -i VidA.ts
-t 10:00 -i VidB.ts
-ss 10:00 -i VidB.ts
-filter_complex "[1:v][1:a][2:v][2:a]concat=n=2:v=1:a=1[c02v][c02a]"
-map 0 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac VidC01.ts
-map [c02v] -map [c02a] -c:v libx264 -c:a aac VidC02.ts
-map 3 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac VidC03.ts
```

I assume all inputs are exactly 15 mins long, and have both a video and audio stream.

Comment: Yes!  That's beautiful and exactly the assumptions I was asking to be made. I'm trying to become familiar with filtergraphs and you provided a great example to help me here.  Thank you so much! 

Out of curiosity, if I wanted to omit, say, the last minute of `VidA.ts`, would I use

    ffmpeg
    -t 12:00 -i VidA.ts
    -ss 12:00 -t 120 -i VidA.ts
    -t 10:00 -i VidB.ts
    ...

or

    ffmpeg
    -t 12:00 -i VidA.ts
    -ss 12:00 -i VidA.ts -to 14:00
    -t 10:00 -i VidB.ts
    ...

or would either/neither work?

Comment: The 2nd input would be `-ss 12:00 -t 2:00 -i VidA.ts` or `-ss 12:00 -to 14:00 -i VidA.ts`